# Shell script for finding similarities between files

Tags: bash, shell

I have two tab delimited files that consist of an ID column and then 20 or so variables. I would like to find those IDs which exist in both files. What I'm asking for is something like the opposite of the bash script 'diff'. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The tool `comm` may be what you want - given sorted input from two files, it can tell you which lines are only in file A, which are in both, and which are only in file B.  For example, if you have `file-a` which is:

```
17 p o i u
13 a b c d
14 q w e r t
```

... and `file-b` which is:

```
18 a s d f 
13 f g h i
7 z x c v
```

You can use `comm` with process substitution in the following way:

```
$ comm -1 -2 <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file-a|sort) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file-b|sort)
13
```

The `-1` parameter suppresses lines that are only in the first file, and `-2` suppresses those that are only in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the files then you can use

```
$ join sortedfile1.txt sortedfile2.txt
```

and you will get the common IDs line joined.

Answer (score 0):

`cut -f1 file1 file2 | sort | uniq -d`